# Cosine-sine decomposition yields zero diagonals

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, singular-values

I have implemented the Cosine-Sine decomposition of a square matrix in Mathematica. That is, for a given matrix $U$ (where in my use-case, $U$ is unitary) with equally-sized partitions
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix} 
U_{00} & U_{01} \\
U_{10} & U_{11}
\end{pmatrix},
$$

I am able to produce the matrices $L_i$, $D_{i}$, $R_i$ satisfying
$$ 
U = \begin{pmatrix} L_0 & \\ & L_1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} D_0 & - D_1 \\ D_1 & D_0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} R_0 & \\ & R_1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $D_i$ are diagonal.

I do this by performing the generalised singular value decomposition (GSVD) of $U_{00}$ with respect to $U_{10}$, as per the second overload of [this function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingularValueDecomposition.html). This directly resolves $L_i$, $D_i$ and $R_0^\dagger$, but does not produce $R_1$. To obtain that, I additionally invert $D_1$ and evaluate

$$
R_1 = - \, D_1^{-1} \, L_0^\dagger \; U_{01}.
$$

Alas, in my use-case, the diagonals of $D_1$ often include $0$, such that $D_1$ is *singular*, precluding me from computing $R_1$.

For example, when
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\
& & & 1 \\
& & 1 \\
& 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
the GSVD yields
$$
L_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\;\;
L_1 = \begin{pmatrix} & -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix},
\;\;
R_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & -1 \end{pmatrix},
\\
D_0 = \text{diag}(1,0,0,0), \;\; D_1 = \text{diag}(0,1,0,0).
$$
It's not hard to show that in fact *no* $R_1$ exists for the above $L_i$, $D_i$, $R_0$ that satisfies the decomposition.

My example seems adverserial. This surprises me, since I understood the only pre-condition of the CS-decomp is that my input matrix is orthogonal, which it *is*; but of course, I am invoking the GSVD only upon partitions $U_{01}$ and $U_{11}$.

My questions are:

- does my example admit no CS decomposition, or is the failure in my particular method of evaluation?
- what is the property of my input matrix (which I can detect for a given arbitrary matrix) that makes it adverserial to my method?
- is there an alternate evaluation of the CS-decomposition, which perhaps invokes the GSVD on *both* columns of $U$, which avoids this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form of the cosine-sine decomposition needs to be modified to allow for 0 or 1 on the diagonal, see for example [Tang & Tian:](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.14324)

[image]

This reference also explains how to obtain the blocks from the singular value decomposition. A complete algorithm is described in [arXiv:0707.1838](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1838).